# igraph radius and diameter

Tags: r, igraph

I'm having a strange problem with igraph functions

I have an undirected graph(N=423) with very high density (0.4). In order to test the values I'm getting from igraph I'm using Gephi.

I've checked with Gephi, and they both report degree and diameter the same
but igraph reports radius and eccentricity completely wrong, much higher values that they should be. Also, radius is always smaller than diameter right? And here it is larger :)

```
> sg <- simplify(graph.edgelist(edges, directed=F))
> radius(sg)
[1] 8
> diameter(sg)
[1] 3
head(eccentricity(sg))
[1] 10 11 10 12 11 14
> str(sg)
IGRAPH U--- 423 41064 -- 
+ edges:
1 --   3   4   6   8   9  15  25  26  28  30  37  38  41  42  47  48  49  50  53  58  63  66  68  69  71  72  76  81  83  87  88  90  95
....etc...
....etc...
```

Gephies eccentricity values are all 2s and 3s which is expected since diameter is 3 :)

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the `eccentricity` routine (`radius` just calls `eccentricity` so the two issues are likely to be related). As a workaround, you can use `shortest.paths` (which seems to be working correctly) and then take the row-wise maximum to get the eccentricity scores. The radius is just the minimum eccentricity.

**Update**: you can follow the progress of the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1081021).

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out in the meantime and it works properly with

ecc <- apply(shortest.paths(sg), 2, max)

Comment: FWIW, I have fixed the bug in the meanwhile. If you are willing to recompile the R extension, download the latest nightly from http://code.google.com/p/igraph from tomorrow. Any revision later than #3014 should be okay.