# R igraph graph density, diameter, eccentricity and shortest path

Tags: r, igraph

I hope someone can help me out.

I have an undirected graph g with n=2071 nodes and m=9023 edges.
I calculated the graph density in R using the igraph package and got the following:

```
> graph.density(g,loop=FALSE)
[1] 0.00210475
```

However, using the formula for graph density, i.e. density = mean degree / (n-1), I got the following:

```
> mean(degree(g))/(vcount(g)-1)
[1] 0.0042095
```

Why does graph.density() give me a different (is it wrong?) answer?

Another question, doesn't the maximum eccentricity = diameter = maximum shortest path of the graph? Or am I confusing the concepts?
Calculating in R using the igraph package, I got the following:

```
> max(shortest.paths(g,mode="all"))
[1] 17
> diameter(g,directed=FALSE,unconnected=FALSE,weights=NULL)
[1] 17
> max(eccentricity(g,mode="all"))
[1] 8
```

I used Gephi to double check and I got the diameter=8.
Why is there a disparity between the values?

Also, I found an almost similar question asked before ([igraph radius and diameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466530/igraph-radius-and-diameter)), but it does not quite ask/answer what I want. It says that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: For undirected graphs you have to multiply your density formula by 2. (Because the number of possible edges in undirected graph is N * (N-1) / 2)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that igraph treats your graph as directed, hence the lower density - note that it is exactly half the density you get from the other formula. This is probably also the reason why the path lengths are longer - if your graph is directed, edges can be followed in only one direction so some paths will inevitably become longer. Check whether igraph treats your graph as undirected with `is.directed(g)`.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently g was unknowingly directed. Once I've corrected it and made sure that g was undirected, the graph density calculated is as expected. However, the max(shortest.paths(g)), diameter(g) and max(eccentricity(g)) still gave me the save answer.

Answer (score 1):

The diameter calculation in igraph considers the edge weights while performing the calculation, so in order to make the calculated diameter same in both igraph and Gephi we need to set weights parameter to 'NA' in igraph.

```
diameter(graph_data, weights = NA)
```